# Can this union be done more elegantly?

Tags: sql, union

I'm trying to see if its possible to search whether a name "alias" exists on either table. If it exists in one or the other I should get one result. If it exists in both, I should get two results. This works, but I'm wondering if the same could be accomplished with a single query instead of a union. I also thought about declaring a variable so I won't have to type in 'test' twice, but I'm not sure what the best method for that is.

```
Select
IDnumber, 
ALIAS 
from IdTABLE
where ALIAS = 'test'
union
Select
IDnumber, 
ALIAS 
from AliasTABLE
where ALIAS = 'test'
;
```

Comment: What you are doing is straight forward and if was reading your code, I know exactly what its trying to do. That should be good enough a reason to say your method is fine. What else are you after?

Comment: The union is straight forward and it shouldn't be slow... so why the concern? 
 Why do you feel union isn't a valid answer?  One could use a full outer join combining the two tables and show 4 columns in the result;  but I agree with the prior comment the union seems fine to me.

Comment: Perhaps you want a `UNION ALL` instead of a `UNION`, which is faster (no need to remove dups)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I think your approach is pretty good and I would probably prefer your code fragment over mine for readability. Non the less in some situations performing the *WHERE-search* only one time might make good sense. So here is a possible restructured version of your code:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  (Select
  IDnumber, ALIAS 
  from IdTABLE)
  UNION
  (Select
  IDnumber, ALIAS 
  from AliasTABLE)
)
WHERE ALIAS ='test';
```

This should give you the same result. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Also, just on a more general note, it is a good idea to review you data scheme, whenever you have such cases, since it might mean, that the data is not perfectly organized (of course it can also be perfectly right to do it this way, but just review it anyways)

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: On a fairly large table (3/4 million records) only took an extra .05 secs to run, so it doesn't impact efficiency much.

Comment: Yeah, the extra time is probably because the UNION operation causes a bigger intermediate result than in your example (since you use UNION on the relations, you already performed the selections on). However, this should not be a exponential problem whatsoever and therefore it probably scales well. Thank you for the solved mark!